# Linker error when compiling homebrew libtorch 2.0.1 with bazel on OS X 13.3.1

Tags: c++, pytorch, homebrew, bazel, libtorch

I'm trying to compile the latest version of libtorch on Mac OS X 13.3.1, installed using homebrew:

```
brew install libtorch
```

using bazel (6.2.1) as the build system. I get the following linker error when I run a minimal example:

```
dyld[21509]: symbol not found in flat namespace '_PyBaseObject_Type'
```

My test command is

```
bazel run -- //examples:hello_torch
```

The minimal example consists of a WORKSPACE file, a BUILD file, and hello_torch.cc (BUILD and hello_torch are in a /examples subdirectory).

WORKSPACE:

```
new_local_repository(
  name = "libtorch_osx_homebrew",
  path = "/usr/local/Cellar/pytorch/2.0.1",
  build_file_content =
"""
cc_library(
    name = "libtorch",
    srcs = glob(["lib/*.dylib"]),
    hdrs = glob(["include/**/*.h", "include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/*.h"]),
    includes = ["include", "include/torch/csrc/api/include/"],
    copts=["-O3"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    linkstatic = 1,
)
"""
)
```

The BUILD file:

```
cc_binary(
  name = "hello_torch",
  srcs = ["hello_torch.cc"],
  deps = ["@libtorch_osx_homebrew//:libtorch"],
  copts=["-std=c++17"],
)
```

hello_torch.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "torch/script.h"
#include "torch/torch.h"

int main() {
  torch::DeviceType device = torch::kCPU;
  torch::Tensor tensor = torch::rand({2, 3}).to(device);
  std::cout << tensor << std::endl;
}
```

I think there is a dependency of the libtorch library that is missing from my definition in the WORKSPACE file to get whatever system or homebrew library defines the _PyBaseObject_Type symbol. I haven't been able to figure out where that should come from. I have looked using tools such as lldb, dtruss, and otool, but haven't found any clues.

Sometimes a 'symbol not found' error like this will say where it is referenced from, but there is no such output in this case, which makes it hard to figure out which dependency of libtorch is using this symbol.

This issue appears somewhat similar: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/51084

Update: another thing I tried is not using homebrew and instead using these files: https://download.pytorch.org/libtorch/cpu/libtorch-macos-2.0.1.zip

This has a different problem. It spams dialogs saying every dylib "cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified" (even when just running this locally for testing).

Comment: You'll need to link to the python libraries

Comment: I have tried, but no luck. Do you have any idea how to link to them in the bazel WORKSPACE file?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the WORKSPACE as follows fixed this particular linker error and enabled me to move on:

```
new_local_repository(
  name = "libtorch_osx_homebrew",
  path = "/usr/local/Cellar/pytorch/2.0.1",
  build_file_content =
"""
cc_library(
    name = "libtorch",
    srcs = [
    "lib/libtorch.dylib",
    #"lib/libtorch_python.dylib",
    "lib/libtorch_global_deps.dylib",
    "lib/libtorch_cpu.dylib",
    "lib/libshm.dylib",
    "lib/libc10.dylib",
    ],
    hdrs = glob(["include/**/*.h", "include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/*.h"]),
    includes = ["include", "include/torch/csrc/api/include/"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
"""
)
```

Note this now explicitly includes some dylibs, and omits libtorch_python.dylib.

This solution is based on a comment here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/63558#issuecomment-1116353447

"symbol not found in flat namespace '_PyBaseObject_Type' error in my Libtorch program ... was resolved by removing/not linking to libtorch_python.dylib"